# Redirect from one api controller method to another, and reapply custom authorize filters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In WebApi I have a controller action that I want to be able to redirect to another ApiController action. I decorate these methods with custom AuthorizeAttribute (`CustomAuthorizaton`) properties so it's imperative that any redirect passes through these incoming security filters.

Here's an example:

```
public class SomeController : ApiController
{

    [CustomAuthorization("Foo")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public CustomResponse SomeMethod(int arg1, int arg2)
    {
        ....
    }
```

}

```
public class AnotherController : ApiController
{

    [CustomAuthorization("Bar")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public CustomResponse AnotherMethod(int arg1, int arg2)
    {
        if(arg1 == 2){

           return Redirect to SomeMethod(...) in SomeController ???

        }


    }
```

}

You'll notice I also return my own custom response object (`CustomResponse` in this example).

So what I need help with is how can I return the `CustomResponse` that results from a redirect, and have that redirect pass through the `CustomAuthorization` filter.

To clarify, calling `AnotherMethod` only requires the `"Bar"` permission, but during a redirect to `SomeMethod` we need to verify that the caller has the `"Foo"` permission also.

It would be a bit of a security hole to just perform the redirect/transfer without checking the caller is authorized correctly to perform the call, particularly as in this case it requires different permissions.

Any help is much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: You need to pass CustomResponse from AnotherMethod to SomeMethod when redirect? Custom filters are applied in case of redirect (return RedirectToAction) too automatically.

Comment: Does my CustomResponse class need to derive from a particular base class for that to work?

Comment: The filters are executed as part of the runtime pipeline before the message get dispatched to the controller. I don't think there is a way to pass that message to a different controller and re-execute the filters. You can do an http redirect, but you will not get the CustomResponse object being pased to the other controller action.

Comment: @Pablo That's what I was afraid of. I'm guessing I should also use 307 Temporary Redirect, rather than 301, because the redirect is conditional?

Comment: @SCRIPTONITE Are you trying to do the redirect server side or client side?  Client side should just work if you return 307.  You could do a serverside redirect more easily if your actions were returning HttpResponseMessage.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Client side is less desirable, but might be only option. I would prefer to handle it server side, but need to at least ensure the redirect will pass through the custom auth filter because the methods require different permissions. If we just transfer from AnotherMethod to SomeMethod without checking, then we have let the caller invoke SomeMethod without the requisite "Foo" permission.

Comment: @SCRIPTONITE you don't need to derive CustomResponse. Look at my answer and try these way of passing data between acitons.

Answer (score 1):

To emulate a redirect without paying the cost of a network round trip you could create an in memory server that has the same configuration as your web API and use a HTTPClient instance to call it.

You do something like this to setup the in-memory server,

```
var httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfiguration)
var httpServer = new HttpServer(httpConfiguration);
```

and then you can make calls to it like this

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpServer);
httpClient.GetAsync("http://mysite.com/mycontroller/redirectUrl");
```

It would be good to store these objects globally somewhere so that you are not recreating them everytime.  HttpClient is threadsafe so there are no worries about re-using it.

This approach ensures that your requests go through the exact same steps as any real network requests (except for the ASP.NET pipeline).

Answer (score -2):

So in case you want to pass data between two get actions you can serialize the object you want to pass - add it to routes and thed do a redirect like

```
return RedirectToAction(ActionName,ControllerName, new { a = Seriliaze(someObject)})
```

then you will be able to deserialize it on the other action and pass to your custom responce. But there will be limitation of url max length.  Or you can try to use a TempData (at least it works nice for Post-Redirect-Get pattern when you need to pass some error etc.)

Comment: RedirectToAction is for MVC not Web API.

Comment: Right @RichardSchneider , then Redirect(Url.RouteUrl()) may help.

Comment: true but then its a client side redirect not server side.